# Manually update tz (time zone) database in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, timezone

Is there a way to manually update the time zone definitions ([“tz” database formerly known as the “Olson database“](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database))?

For example, the Java platform provides the [TZUpdater tool](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html) to install, and even build, a fresh copy of the tz data.

Is there some such tool or workaround for Mac OS X?

I know Apple tends to include updates to the tz database as a part of the regular system updates. But sometimes last minute changes are made to take effect sooner than Apple may release a system update. Also, for older versions of Mac OS X no longer updated by Apple may need fresh time zone data.

Answer (score 2):

The FreeBSD location is

```
/usr/share/zoneinfo
```

and the files are there on MacOSX 10.10.5. I'm not sure if updates to those files will be respected by OSX but it's a good place to start.